# VPN only network setup?

Tags: vpn

I'm looking to set up a VPN server and I'm trying to figure out what software to use. My problem is that *I have no idea what the term for the arrangement I want is* so I can't really google for it. What I want is to have a "virtual" LAN where the only access is by VPN, where having access to the VPN only give you access to other VPN *clients*; not to the general internet, and not to the server running the VPN.

My primary use case is getting uniform access between clients I own where one or both may be behind a NAT and/or firewall that may not have a consistent IP.

(p.s. Given my budget I'll have to stick with freeware/FOSS.)

Edit: The VPN server is not in the same NAT/Firewall/IP situation. It's able to serve up whatever I want from a static IP.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy working with OpenBSD (PF) along with OpenVPN you can create the type of setup you are looking for...if I understand properly.

When I fist got my hands on PF I found that documentation very enlightening.
http://www.kernel-panic.it/openbsd/vpn/index.html

Comment: OK so OpenVPN can do what I'm asking for. What do they call it? (The docs are 40+ pages long and nothing in the table of contents jumps out at me.)

Comment: Well, it's a bit complicated but what I would do is giving the VPN users a second IP address in a subnet that only includes VPN users. Somewhere in the OpenVPN setup you have to tell it what IP range it can provide to VPN clients. If you go here http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html and look for the keyword "range" you should land on the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with OpenVPN.

There are two gotchas however:

1. Configure routing/firewall on router in a way that will block packets between tun interface and other interfaces.
2. enable `client-to-client` in openvpn config (just add it in .conf file on server)

OpenVPN by default will provide same IP address to client on reconnect. There are cases where it may not happen: pool running out of IPs, configuration moved to other server without files in /var, etc.

To assure same IP on reconnects, use `client-config-dir` directive. In it you create files with the same name as the DN of client's certificate, then it's just add there

`ifconfig-push <ip-of-server-in-vpn> <ip-of-client>`

where server's IP is the one on tun interface (private IP)

Comment: I'm not sure how that relates to the things I'm looking for. How do I prevent the VPN clients from having access (via the VPN) to anything but the other VPN clients (including access to the hosting server)?

Comment: using iptables: `iptables -I FORWARD -o tun0 -j DROP`, `iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -j DROP`. Linux doesn't threat tun interfaces in any special way as far as routing or firewalling is concerned. You need to configure typical routing on a multihomed host.

Comment: OK, but how do I prevent the server from getting a tun0 interface in the first place?

Comment: Adding above rules *will* block access to and from server in VPN. If you can't trust server on which VPN works you'll need to build a two level VPN: the above mentioned one to get access to second, secure one.